# Read JSON response object in php/js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to display particular values of response object in HTML. But I am not able to display those values.

With `json.stringify(data)` I can convert response to string. I want to show Status and StatusCode to user. How can I get these values?

[image: demo]

```
<script>
$jq.ajax({
    url: 'api url',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        var JSONString =JSON.stringify(data);

        //var json = $jq.parseJSON(data);
        $jq.each(data.ShipmentData, function(index, value){
           // alert(JSON.stringify(value));
          //console.log(value);
          //console.log(JSON.stringify(Shipment));
        });

    },
    error: function() {
        alert("FAIL");
    }
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to stringify your data!

You just have to access the object properties. Like this:

```
$jq.each(data.ShipmentData, function(){
    console.log(this.Shipment.Status.Status);
    console.log(this.Shipment.Status.StatusCode);
});
```

where `this` is the *current* object of the each iteration

Answer (score -2):

Try to use JSON.parse instead of JSON.stringify if you want to use object in each loop.

```
var obj = jq.parseJSON(data);
for(var i= 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    console.log(obj[i]); 
}
```

Comment: thnx for d reply. but it wont work. it thrws /SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data/